# Unity: how to update only the Windows executable?

Tags: unity, windows

Suppose I made a small changes to the source code of my game. No assets, textures or sounds are changed.

How can I create a "patch" or "update" for the Windows build of my game so my customers don't need to re-download everything?

Comment: That's why you have custom launchers like Steam or other external applications, that check on given mechanics, which files have changed and only supply the changed files to the user. You can write your own launcher that does this (not that hard) but that is the way to go

Comment: @YoshSynergi Back in the pre-Steam era, game studios used to release patches for their games in form of small, self-executing installers. The technology should still exist.